# what's a simple way to search a very long text file for a word in python?

Tags: python, list, search, performance, spell-checking

I want to create a very simple spell checker using a text file with an alphabetized list of about 80000 common words.

What's a simple but efficient way to search the file and find out if it contains a word using python?

Should I parse the word list file into a set, list, dictionary, tuple?

Is there an easy way to take advantage of the fact that my word list is already alphabetized?

I'd prefer to keep it relatively simple. I don't want corrected spelling recommendations or other fancy features. I just want to know if the word is miss-spelled.

Comment: Depends on how many words you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 80000 words will easily fit in memory, you are best off using a `set`:

```
words = set(line.strip() for line in open("words"))
```

This won't take advantage of the fact that your file is already sorted, but it is the most efficient way anyway.  To look up a word `w`, you can use

```
w in words
```

which is amortised O(1).

Comment: Use `with open("words") as f:`, relying on refcounting to close files is so last 2.4 ;)

Comment: ...in the average case. In the worst case, it's O(n). @delnan if you only need a file once, his method is clean.

Comment: @Rafe: That's nitpicking (nothing against nitpicking, but it should be marked as such) - you need some **really** bad luck to get so many collisions; for all practical purposes, one can assume O(1). And re. files: Regardless of how long you need the file, it's better to close the file manually (i.e. through a context manager). Especially with e.g. PyPy, which can't close the file until the next GC run, getting more and more production-ready.

Comment: @delnan that's interesting. I guess I'd better learn a bit more about PyPy, I'll probably start using it soon.

Comment: By the way, this applies for *all* implementations not using refcounting in favour of a more sophisticated (and better-performing) GC, which is about every single one except CPython - Jython and IronPython inherit such GCs from their host VMs, for instance. Reason being, of course, that such GCs don't keep track of reachability in realtime but only search for garbage once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Put your dict words in a set which has a constant lookup time.

```
myDict = set([<actual list of words here>])
for word in file:
    if word not in myDict:
        handleBadWord(word)
```